# How to use multiple printers

Tags: php

I need to connect printer using my PHP based web application. All the printers are shared in network or it may be IP printer.

Comment: What does it have to do with mysqli?

Comment: I used mysql as a database thats why i mentioned it

Comment: And what's your question about this?

Comment: What have you tried?  Are the users of the web page able to connect to "All the printers" your PHP application has access to?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to do it with an IP printer, note that it doesn't account for interruptions in the transfer or anything, just a basic version to base yourself on:

```php
$ip = "your IP here";
$file = "path to the file to print";

// Opening socket
if(!$fs = @fsockopen($ip, 9100)) {
    echo "Unable to connect to the printer.";
    die();
}

// Sending file to printer
fwrite($fs, file_get_contents($file));

// Closing socket
fclose($fs);
```